# How to Interpret Census Table Headers

Tags: data, attribute-table, census

I'm wondering if there is a way to decipher the headers for this census data for a project I'm working on?

I've tried googling and I cannot find much info on it.

[image]

Comment: I think this question would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Where are you downloading this data? The Census provides 1,000s of data dumps...

Comment: I retrieved the data from the census website here under the 2010- 1014 Detailed Tables> Census Tract> Georgia: [link]http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I retrieved the data from the census website here under the 2010- 1014 Detailed Tables> Census Tract> Georgia: [link]census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html – Andrew 4 mins ago

click the link you just provided. Scroll down to [TRACT METADATA](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_DP/2014ACS/Metadata/TRACT_METADATA_2014.txt), because you downloaded a Census *Tract*.

That's what the columns reflect..

```
Short_Name  Full_Name
B00001e1    UNWEIGHTED SAMPLE COUNT OF THE POPULATION: Total: Total population -- (Estimate)
B00001m1    UNWEIGHTED SAMPLE COUNT OF THE POPULATION: Total: Total population -- (Margin of Error)
B00002e1    UNWEIGHTED SAMPLE HOUSING UNITS: Total: Housing units -- (Estimate)
B00002m1    UNWEIGHTED SAMPLE HOUSING UNITS: Total: Housing units -- (Margin of Error)
B01001e1    SEX BY AGE: Total: Total population -- (Estimate)
B01001m1    SEX BY AGE: Total: Total population -- (Margin of Error)
... and on and on..
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Do you know if there is an easier or more refined source of high school graduation rates that I can use to join and display in arcMap?

Comment: Not that I know of. Find the column name you want, and query it.